# saltstack get the command execution stdout real time for long running process

Tags: salt-stack

Am working on automation area for the application patching through saltstack and the actual patching takes hours to completed. In saltstack(based on my understanding), I noticed that the output of the execution can be accessed only after the completion of the jobs. I tried to find the way to look for the possibilities to pull the partial execution stdout & stderr(if any) in between the execution, probabliy every 15mins once until the execution completes. But I didn't get any luck and found that there was a old discussion for the same on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/salt-users/ikAVtZnuB30. Since that thread for too old I would like to know is there any way available to fetch the execution stdout periodically for the long running jobs. Otherwise we don't know what is happening on the execution and it becomes very hard to login into each of the application servers to check whats going on. If still there is no such feature available I would like to know is there any workaround available for this case at least.

I found that salt minion stores the job details in the minion cache folder until the job completes, so after struggling a lot thought of writing a script to check for running job details by looking at the minion cache folder. But the cache folder doesn't contain the execution stdout/stderr and it just contains the job details only which was sent from master. Also as far my understanding salt uses subprocess to spawn the commands and upon the script/command completion it gets the subprocess stdout and stderr which is returned to master(based on debugging). As the saltstack is growing these days I believe many of them needed the feature to stream the stdout/stderr periodically to know exactly whats happening on the remote machine after the job is triggered, I tried to check the docs as well and couldn't anything. So any of salstack experts can provide some lights on my query.